# fixing tabulation in c programming

Tags: c

I have a file that contains id, year, name of movies, like this:

```
1   Toy Story   1995    
2   GoldenEye   1995        
3   Four Rooms  1995        
4   Get Shorty  1995    
5   Copycat 1995    
6   Shanghai Triad (Yao a yao yao dao waipo qiao)   1995
```

I got this to the struct from the file.

Now I want to print that and I have a problem with that.

---

My code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
struct Movies {
   char MID[50];
   char MName[50];
   char MYear[50];
}

Movie[100];
FILE *MovieF;

int main() {
    printf("------------------\n");
    printf("Disply Movies \n");
    printf("------------------\n");
    printf("Movie id\t\tMovie name\t\t\t\t\tYear\n");
    printf("--------\t\t----------\t\t\t\t\t--------\n");
    MovieF = fopen("d:\\movies.txt","r");
    for(int i=0;i<60;i++) {
        fscanf(MovieF, "%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t\n",Movie[i].MID,Movie[i].MName,Movie[i].MYear);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<60;i++) {
        printf("%s\t\t%s\t\t\t\t\t%s\n",Movie[i].MID,Movie[i].MName,Movie[i].MYear);        
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I can't print that in the right column.

And this is the current (not wanted) output:

```
------------------
Disply Movies
------------------
Movie id                Movie name                                      Year
--------                ----------                                      --------
1               Toy Story                                       1995
2               GoldenEye                                       1995
3               Four Rooms                                      1995
4               Get Shorty                                      1995
5               Copycat                                 1995
6               Shanghai Triad (Yao a yao yao dao waipo qiao)                                   1995
```

---

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: maybe use a third-party library like [this](https://github.com/seleznevae/libfort)?

Comment: Specify field width instead of using tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to solve such problems is to first look at the fields. Movie Name seems to be a string which will vary in length. By calculating the longest string and then buffering for it, the table will look as intended. Here is your code that I modified. I calculate the max length and then for each print, find the difference and add that many spaces.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    struct Movies
    {
       char MID[50];
       char MName[50];
       char MYear[50];
    }Movie[100];
    FILE *MovieF;
    // could be more optimized, but it is a simple quick and dirty way to get max
    int findmax()
    {
        int max = 0;
        int temp = 0;
        for (int i=0;i<60;i++)
        {   
            temp = strlen(Movie[i].MName);
            if (temp > max) max = temp;
        }
        return max;
    }

    int main()
    {
        int maxMovLen = 0;
        char line[1024];
        int i = 0;
        printf("------------------\n");
        printf("Disply Movies \n");
        printf("------------------\n");
        // Add your code here to read the lines from your file
        // read_csv(60, 3, "movies.txt");
        
        maxMovLen = findmax();
        // chose 10 spaces as separator 
        printf("Movie id%*s", 10, "");
        printf("Movie name%*s", maxMovLen, "");
        printf("Year\n");
        // chose 10 spaces as separator
        printf("--------%*s", 10, "");
        printf("----------%*s", maxMovLen, "");
        printf("----\n");
        for(int i=0;i<60;i++)
        {
            // chose 10 spaces as separator
            printf("%4s%*s\t", Movie[i].MID, 10, "");
            printf(" %s%*s\t", Movie[i].MName, maxMovLen-strlen(Movie[i].MName), "");
            // chose 10 spaces as separator
            printf("%10s\t\n", Movie[i].MYear);    
        }   
        return 0;
    }
```

This is the output from running my code

```
Disply Movies 
------------------
Movie id          Movie name                     Year
--------          ----------                     ----
   1             hello world people              1995
    
   2             hello world                     1995
    
   3             hello world people2             1995
    
   4             hello world                     1995
    
   5             hello world people3             1995
    
   6             hello world world               1995
    
   7             hello world5                    1995
    
   8             hello world                     1995
    
   9             hello world                     1995
    
  10             hello world                     1995
    
  11             hello world                     1997
    
  12             hello world                     1999
    
  13             hello world                     2001
    
  14             hello world                     2003
    
  15             hello world                     2005
    
  16             hello world                     2007
    
  17             hello world                     2009
    
  18             hello world                     2011
```

Comment: I missed looking at @jiandingzhe answer. Which is similar to what I propose. With proper buffering of Movie length you should get what you desire.

Answer (score 2):

No you can never approach that kind of pretty formatting using tabs merely.

Sticking to `printf`, you could use `%*s` format that specifies space occupation. It requires an extra number argument before the string. A positive number means right-aligned, and negative number means left-aligned. For example:

```
printf("<%*s>", 5, "abc"); // give you <  abc>
printf("<%*s>", -5, "abc"); // give you <abc  >
```

Answer (score 1):

Print header and data using a common set of minimum character *widths*.
Specify field width instead of using tabs [@Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62812996/fixing-tabulation-in-c-programming/62819240#comment111077550_62812996).

Easy to manage.

```
int id_width = 3*8;   // Minimum widths
int name_wdith = 6*8;
int year_wdith = 1;

printf("%-*s%-*s%-*s\n", 
    id_width, "Movie id", name_width, "Movie name", year_width, "Year");
printf("%-*s%-*s%-*s\n", 
    id_width, "--------", name_width, "----------", year_width, "--------");

...

for(int i=0;i<60;i++) {
  printf("%-*s%-*s%-*s\n", 
      id_width, Movie[i].MID, name_width, Movie[i].MName, year_width, Movie[i].MYear);
```